# jQuery to track Google analytics events not working

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use google anayltics events but so far without any success..

What I'm doing is loading 5 pages using jQuery load function
and I want to track the "Next button" for each load. but looks like i'm doing something wrong..

This is the next button event code:

```
            $('.NextButton').click(function () {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'fz_main_page', 'clicked']);
                installation.load_page({ inner_page: next_page, comid: data.comid, outerid: data.outerid, single_app: "1" });
            });
```

Analytics Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25162785-2']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the `installation.load_page` function is preventing the `trackEvent` from firing. Try wrapping your `load` function in a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout('installation.load_page({ inner_page: next_page, comid: data.comid, outerid: data.outerid, single_app: "1" })', 100);
```

Install the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna). Look in the console (control, shift, j) for the event tracking processing.

[image]

If you don't see all of your events tracking there, then something else is up with the tracking code.

Comment: Alternatively you could fire the event on mousedown instead of click. The mousedown happens roughly 50ms-200ms before the actual click. So you don't have to mess with timeouts