# Google Analytics - Track 'Add to cart'

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to add tracking code on the add to cart button, but for some reason the data is not sent over to google.

```
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Products', 'Add to Cart', 'skuproductcode', jQuery('select#qty').val()])">Add to Cart</button>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Should I push the transaction or is it being pushed automatically to Google?

I've activated Ecommerce tracking on Google Analytics. Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: The `submit` function may be preventing the `_trackEvent` from firing. What is happening with the form on submit? If it's going to another page, the event tracking is not being recorded.

Comment: It's an AJAX call. Should I do the `_gaq.push` before `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)`? Also, should I push the transaction or it's being pushed by itself?

Comment: Install the Chrome browser and the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna). Look in the console (control, shift, j) for the event tracking processing. If it's not appearing there, then it's not being called. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395364/jquery-to-track-google-analytics-events-not-working/10398812#10398812 for more on the GA debugging of events.

Comment: try this: http://www.ganotes.com/track-add-cart-events-google-analytics-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need ecommerce tracking for event tracking. You should add a helper function that

- calls the event tracking
- introduces a short timeout so there's time for the event tracking pixel to be send to the google server before the page is redirected to the form's target url
- then submits the form.

and call this helper function in your click event.

However if you want to "push a transaction" you should look for "Transaction tracking" in the Analytics documentation because that's quite a different thing from event tracking.